Understanding console.log() within functions vs. using return in JavaScript?
I'm learning about functions in JavaScript and I'm confused about the role of console.log() and return.
function reusableFunction() {
  console.log("Hi World");
}

reusableFunction(); 

I understand this function logs "Hi World" to the console. My questions are:

Why doesn't this function need a return statement? I've seen other functions that are used return to send values back. Is console.log() doing something similar?

Why do we call the function with just reusableFunction(); instead of console.log(reusableFunction());? When would I use the second way of calling the function?


I'm trying to understand the fundamental difference between displaying something in the console  console.log()   and returning a value from a function. Can you explain this with clear examples and perhaps point me to some           resources for further learning?
I tried reading Documents like MDN, JS, and Google Developer Docs. I even did a Google Search and kept getting the basics. It answered my question. I just simply want to know when you know to use a return statement in your functions and when to console.log() and then call the function, like this console.log(reusableFunction()) . I understand what console.log() is what the return statement is and the difference between both.

console.log() literally only logs to the console. Not all functions require a return statement. You would use console.log(reusableFunction()); when you want to log the return value of reusableFunction.

Some functions may just manipulate the DOM and not require a return statement. Others do a calculation and hand the result back to the caller.

the key point here is that reusableFunction() is an expression which evaluates to whatever the function returns (as determined by a return statement inside it), and "as a side effect" also executes the code inside the function

The console facility is a fairly recent addition to the world of JavaScript. The console is a service for debugging and inspecting code in a page. There is absolutely nothing fundamental about the console in JavaScript; it's just a facility provided by JavaScript environments. People wrote JavaScript code for many years without it.

These are the detailed answers to both of your questions. I hope the answer will help you understand and clarify the concepts
Why doesn't this function need a return statement?
Functions don't necessarily need a return statement unless they're supposed to produce a value. Here's why:

console.log() is used for outputting information to the console.
It doesn't return anything; it just prints to the console.
Functions that only use console.log() are typically used for side effects
(likeprinting to the console).

Why call the function with just reusableFunction() instead of console.log(reusableFunction());?

reusableFunction() calls the function and executes its body.
console.log(reusableFunction()) would pass the function's return value itself as an argument to console.log().
The latter is rarely used unless you want to log the function's return value.

Fundamental differences between displaying and returning values

Displaying values (using console.log()):


Used for outputting information to the console.
Doesn't produce a value that can be assigned to variables.
Useful for debugging and logging.


Returning values:


Produces a value that can be captured and used elsewhere.
Can be assigned to variables or returned from functions.
Allows for function composition and passing data between functions.


yeah agreed sir, typing mistake @RobinZigmond, going to correct it

To answer #1:
The function itself simply does not return a value. That is an option for a function, to do some processing on some data and return the result, or a function can just do some processing and that's it.
I think an analogy could be the difference between
Going to the post office to deliver a letter (no return value)
vs.
Going to the post office to pick up a package and do something with that package at home
#2
When you write Console.Log(reusableFunction()), you are simply combining these two items together. This would make more sense if 'reusableFunction()' were returning a result (as descibed in #1). In this case, it doesn't really make sense because what you're saying in essence is
Log this value to the console -> {returned value from function, which happens to not really be a value}

But, like I mentioned, there is no returned value here. Now, you're still calling the function, so the log line from within (console.log("Hi World");
) will execute as intended. But, this would be an unorthodox way of achieving this.
I hope this helps.
